# How to publish "master" branch pages instead of "gh-pages"?

Tags: git, github

Form the document [user-organization-and-project-pages.](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages.)

User & Organization Pages live in a special repository dedicated to only the Pages files...

- *Content from the master branch will be used to build and publish the Pages.*

"Unlike User and Org Pages, Project Pages are kept in the same repository as the project they are for....

- *The gh-pages branch is used to build and publish from.*

So if i have a public repository my project page will be available as `"gh-graph"` branch and  it will be available in the url `http://username.github.io/projectname`.

**But how can I publish the content in master page to this url. ? or how can I create a user/org page?**

what is the actual difference between user/org pages and project pages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User/org pages are served from `http://username.github.io`. Their content lives in the `master` branch of the repository `username/username.github.io` (`http://github.com/username/username.github.io.git` exactly).

Project pages are served from `http://username.github.io/proj`. Their content lives in the `gh-pages` branch of the repository `username/proj`.

My `user` page is here https://github.com/snaewe/snaewe.github.com for example (nothing fancy, just auto-created) -> http://snaewe.github.io

A sample `project` page is here: https://github.com/snaewe/MPC/tree/gh-pages -> http://snaewe.github.io/MPC

**Note:** I created those pages when github used `...github.com` as the domain name. Today it's `...github.io`.

If you have an `index.html` in the `master` branch of your project and want to use that as the project page, just push the `master` branch to the `gh-pages` branch in your github project:

```
git push origin master:gh-pages
```